# Can WebSecurity work in WCF services?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, webmatrix

I am new in the SimpleMembership model. WebSecurity works fine in the Web pages, but I have problems when I use it in the services.

I have some web services, working under:

```
<binding name="SecureBasicBindingWithMembershipConfig">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
           <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
           <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
</binding>
```

I try to recover the user Id from a web service.

If I use `WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated`, it returns `IsAuthenticated = 'WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException'`

However, using  `System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser()` the user Id is correctly returned.

Can WebSecurity be used within a WCF service or I am doing something wrong?